# Anglularjs passing value from Controller, State Resolve and Factory Service

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-controller

Okay, I have three relevant files for my question/s..

**App.js** - app.config

In my `app.config` passing value in the `resolve` using `$stateParams` is possible and I attain it. But how about the value is from the `controller`? I need the `provCode` value to use it in my `php select query`.

```
.state("editStudent", {
    abstract: true,
    url:"/student/:id",
    controller: "EditStudentController",
    templateUrl: "views/students/editStudent.html",
    resolve: {
      dataservice: 'dataservice',
      student: function(dataservice, $stateParams){
        var data ={ 
          id : $stateParams.id
        };
        return dataservice.getStudent(data);
      },
      provinceData: function(dataservice){
        return dataservice.getProvince();
      },
      municipalityData: function(dataservice){
        var provCode = {
          provCode : '0456'    // <--------------------- this one 
        }
        return dataservice.getCity(provCode);
      }

    }
    })
```

**EditStudentController.js** - app.controller

In my `app.controller`, I use the `angular.forEach` to find `province` `code` or `id` to use it `php select query`. As you can see I tried to create function `app.getCity` but it is not working as I expected.

```
console.log(provinceData);
$scope.provinceData = provinceData;


var retProv = $scope.studentInfo.province;

angular.forEach(provinceData, function(value, key) {
    if(value.provDesc == retProv){
    $scope.studentInfo.province = provinceData[key];
    $scope.provCode =  provinceData[key].provCode;
    console.log($scope.provCode); 
    }   
}); // angular.forEach

var provCode = $scope.provCode;

// Test if it is working but sadly, it is not 
// $scope.getCity = function(){
//    dataservice.getCity(provCode);
// }
```

**Dataservice.js** - app.factory

In my `app.factory` there are currently 3 functions. The other 2 functions works expectedly but the `factory.getCity()` is my problem right now. As you can see there is a parameter `provCode`, this parameter is from my `app.config` `state` `resolve` and it has been assigned a hardcoded/static value.

```
factory.getStudent = function(data){
    return $http.post("php/students/viewOneStudent.php",data).then(function(response){
        student = response.data[0];
        console.log(student);
        return student;
    })
}

factory.getProvince = function(){
    return $http.get('php/address/province.php').then(function(response){
        provinceData = response.data;
        console.log(provinceData); 
        return provinceData;
    })
}

factory.getCity = function(provCode){
    return $http.post('php/address/cities.php', provCode).then(function(response){
        municipalityData = response.data;
        console.log(municipalityData);  
        return municipalityData;
    })
}
```

**My Question is:**

1. If it is possible to pass a value from `controller` to a `resolve`?
2. If it is possible, how can I do that? because I tried my very best in trial and error approach.
3. If it is not possible, what is my option/s to achieve what I want?

**Note**

I tried to do it without `resolve`, getting data and posting again for `php querying`, it is also works BUT the problem is sometimes data doesn't load when the `view` is loaded. As far as I know, read and understand from different sources in the internet, there is a time that `view` is loaded but the "work on processing the data" is not finished yet..

I am pretty new and still learning AngularJs. When I am practicing and learning AngularJs coding, I love how it works especially the `routing`, I am impressed with it. So, I am trying my very best to understand AngularJs and its complexity.

**UPDATE**
I tried different approach of how I can get my expected results. But I can't get to it, I encountered an error. This is the link of my other approach.

[Undefined property: stdClass: in using AngularJS + PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580982/undefined-property-stdclass-in-using-angularjs-php)