# Undefined property: stdClass: in using AngularJS + PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am trying to get the `provCode` or `ID` from the `provinceData` from `getFunction()`. I did that by using `angular.forEach()`, but I didn't expected to get the following error.

**Notice**:  Undefined property: stdClass::$provCode in **C:\xampp\htdocs\student-violation-system\php\address\cities.php** on line **5**
[]

I tried to change the `{provCode: provCode}` to just `provCode` also not working.

So, I tried to change the `{provCode: provCode}` to `{provCode: '0456'}` and it works.

But ofcourse it is not what I want, I want it to be dynamic. I wonder why it is saying the `Undefined property` because I tried to `console.log` the `provCode` inside the `getCity()` and it has a expected value of `0456`. So, I wonder why it is saying `Undefined property`.

**app.factory**

```
factory.getProvince = function(){
    return $http.get('php/address/province.php').then(function(response){
        provinceData = response.data;
        console.log(provinceData); 

        angular.forEach(provinceData, function(value, key) {
            if(value.provDesc == province){
                provCode =  provinceData[key].provCode;
            }   
        }); // angular.forEach

        return provinceData;
    })
}

factory.getCity = function(){
    return $http.post('php/address/cities.php', {provCode: provCode}).then(function(response){

        console.log(provCode);

        municipalityData = response.data;
        console.log(municipalityData);  
        return municipalityData;
    })
}


return factory;
```

**cities.php**

```
<?php 
include("../../connection.php");

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$provCode = $data->provCode;

$db->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$cities = $db->query(" SELECT * FROM refcitymun WHERE provCode='$provCode' ");

$cities = $cities->fetchAll();

echo json_encode($cities);
?>
```

**UPDATE**

I log the `$data` in **cities.php** and it was returning `null` value. I don't know why because I `console.log` the `provCode` inside the `getCity` function and it is returning the right value/data I was expecting. Can someone explain it to me what is happening? My mind is going crazy on this one.

By the way it is one of my ongoing approach on how to solve my issue on this: [Anglularjs passing value from Controller, State Resolve and Factory Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579885/anglularjs-passing-value-from-controller-state-resolve-and-factory-service)

Comment: Once log `$data` and see whether you are getting data or not.

Comment: how can i log the $data?

Comment: i log the $data, and it was returning `null`

Comment: Do you get data from `get` call and able to store in `provCode`? Once look at it.

Comment: Yes, I am getting the right data from the `get` call and it is perfectly stored in the `provCode`. How do I know? Because I `console.log(provCode)` inside the `$http.get` function right before the line of `return provinceData`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're defining `provCode` as a global variable. Try declaring it as a private variable of the factory first.

Example

```
function MyFactory($http) {
  let provCode = 0;
  return {
    getProvince: function () {
      return $http.get('php/address/province.php')
        .then(function(response){
          // do some stuff
          angular.forEach(provinceData, function(value, key) {
            if(value.provDesc == province){
              provCode =  provinceData[key].provCode;
            }   
          }); // angular.forEach
        })
    },
    getCity: function() {
      return $http.post('php/address/cities.php', {provCode: provCode})
        .then(function(response){
          // do some stuff
        })
    }
  };
}
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('MyFactory', MyFactory);
```

Comment: `provCode` is already declared inside my `app.factory`

`app.factory('dataservice', function($stateParams, $http){
    var factory = {};
    var provCode;

}`